# posting value from one view to another on the link click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got two views namely Index view and Createdialog view.
The code for index view is:

```
<p>Search For: &nbsp;</p>
@Html.TextBox("companyName", Model);
```

and the code for Createdialog view is:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.branch)
{    

    <tr>
    <td><a href="#">   
    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.companyName)
    </a></td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.branchName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.address)</td>
    <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.branchId })
    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = item.companyName })
   </td>
</tr>      
}
```

Now I want to do is, to send the value of company id from createdialog view to index dialog view and show the companyName in the textbox when i click the select link. Provide suggestion... thank you.

Comment: Do you want to show in popup or redirect to Index view?

Comment: I wanted to redirect to the index view, and show the value in the textbox situated in the index view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "send values" from one View to another in MVC.  Instead, you will send data from the View to a Controller action and then display another View.

What you have is close, but what you'll want to do in the Controller is to accept the `companyName` as an input parameter like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // Perform any initialization or other operations

    // Show the Index view with the id (the companyName) as the Model
    return View("Index", id);
}
```

Comment: but i wanted to post the value from an action link and i've not done passing the value from an action link.. So will you provide me suggestion or post some codes for that. Thank you..

Comment: Updated answer should give you what you want.

Comment: I did same as you suggested.                                       public ActionResult Select(string id)
        {
            return View("Index", id);
        }                                                          This shows the error like:The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. How can I get rid of this problem.

Comment: You need to create an Index view, but I thought you already had this.

Answer (score 1):

in your view u should get something like this:

instead of

```
<td><a href="#">   
    @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.companyName)
</a></td>
```

use

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.companyName, "Index", new { name = item.companyName })
```

capture it in the controller with

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View("Index", name);
}
```

Good luck :)